# Render model at center position not displaying (revised)

Tags: c++, shader, render, opengl-3, sdl-2

Currently I can load a model of earth from a DAE file without a texture just to show that something is on the screen. To do this, I used **GLU.**

But now I'm trying to us **GLM and shaders** to load the model with a texture. The problem I'm having is properly getting them both to work together to display the model.

**REVISED**

After being pointed out that I needed VAOs to render an scene, I decided to go with a previously mentioned example from **[ogldev's tutorial 32 about Vertex Array Objects.](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial32/tutorial32.html)** I compiled the tutorial and it works as it should, but it is **GLUT.** So I extracted the vital parts pertaining to loading the models and implemented them into my project. After some debugging, I've managed to end up further than previously described, but still nothing shows. And after looking back and forth as to what I may have missed, I can't pinpoint the exact problem. I made sure that the program is reading values and doing proper checks that show that the procedure is valid with no hiccups, but I for some reason, I can't get anything to show up. I've changed the background color to check if there was just a silhouette of the earth model, but nothing still rendered to the screen.

What I have done is provided a copy of I've done. Everything is showing an appropriate value. If you compare the tutorial versus mine, you will see that it's the same thing and besides mine hard-coding the camera position and target to point to where the model is to be, there is really nothing different. But I don't know what I may have missed/overlooked in the process.

*(non expiring)*

[**game.cpp**](http://pastebin.com/4pww3E6d)
 Everything within **OnInit()** passes. But when it comes to `OnRender()`, Something isn't right.

[**PipeLine.cpp**](http://pastebin.com/1wDTQceZ)
No different from the tutorial.

[**model.cpp**](http://pastebin.com/J4WLY1SU)
Other than the class name, no different than the tutorial.

[**Technique.h & cpp**](http://pastebin.com/cVMCdEVJ)
Shaders and Shader Program. No different than the tutorial.

[**Lighting.h & cpp**](http://pastebin.com/w6UJDPW0)
Child of Technique class. Gets uniforms, etc.

Comment: did you check _cam variable?

Comment: @SAKrisT Yes. The Camera is set to be 20 units away and aiming at the center.

Comment: What happens inside Model::Render()?

Comment: @glampert I've updated it showing how it's suppose to be drawn.

Comment: Two things I could spot: 
1) You are ignoring the third vertex element in your shader. But this is not very likely to be your problem.
2) You are not using a Vertex Array Object (VAO), which I'm pretty sure is required for core OpenGL rendering. Maybe take a look at: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial32/tutorial32.html

Comment: @glampert I've tried that version, but it's too unorganized to follow along

Comment: OK, I was just pointing you to some resources on VAOs. Still, I think you should give the VAO a try. Another suggestion that I can give you right now is to call glGetError() more often. Actually, you should definitely define a macro and call it after every GL call. But make sure to disable the macro on release builds, it has some runtime overhead, but is helpful during development.

Comment: @glampert you were right about VAOs. The problem remains when it comes to getting GLM and shaders to play nicely.

Comment: That last glm::translate before m_mode.Render() won't have any effect, since you are not attributing the return value to anything. Not sure what is the intention there. Also, in the glm::lookAt call, you have fixed the camera's target to (0,0,0). Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be in your fragment definition:

```
fragData = color * texture(tex, TexCoord);
```

where color is defined as an uniform. In your main program you don't allocated any value to it, so, it is initialized to zero, which makes any fragment be black. The same color of your framebuffer background.

Despite this, there are others issues with your code. First, you are using a lot of deprecated functions that has no effect in core profile (v3.3).

Second you need to allocate a VAO (Vertex Array Object) to be able to see anything.

And, finally, some functions seems not to have any effects, like, for example:

```
glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, -20.f)); // <-----------

// Draw model
m_model.Render();
```

It would easier to help you if you provide the implemantation of your `render` function.

Comment: I had to revise the problem. It should be much clearer to understand what is happening now.